# Selenium Webdriver: why can't it find all HTML elements of certain class?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I opened the webpage https://www.themarker.com/law/1.7254050 in the browser and I saw 12 elements which have a class "cmt__title".

However, when I ran the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/matan/chrome-driver/chromedriver", options=options)

driver.get("https://www.themarker.com/law/1.7254050")
titles = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('cmt__title')

print(titles)
```

I got a list of only 2 HTML elements. How can it be?

Comment: Seems like there are just 2 elements on initial page load. Other elements with this class are loaded when you scroll down to comment section.

Comment: Unfortunately, scrolling to the bottom with selenium and sleeping for 10 seconds before `find` still didn't do the trick :\

Comment: try calculating the height from top to bottom and scrolling in timed sections to bottom. I see 57 btw.